# What kind of vocabulary can be used when the person doesn't like thing that he/she has to have?

Tags: vocabulary

What kind of vocabulary can be used when the person doesn't like thing that he/she has to have?  For example, I have crutches and I have to use them, but I really don't want to.

Answer (score 2):

> I have crutches and I have to use them, but I really don't want to: 
>   they are a **necessary evil**.

This is a venerable trope for something distasteful yet unavoidable.  Google books takes me to an 1818 edition of Sir Francis Bacon's *Essays, or Counsels Civil and Moral* in which the phrase appears.  The essays were published in 1625.

Comment: Apart from earlier citations, I'd add that it is a current common expression: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+necessary+evil

Comment: The OED refers it back to a Greek phrase (Menander), and gives a quote dated 1547 (W. Baldwin).

Answer (score 0):

To ***[tolerate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/tolerate)*** suggests the idea of having to accept something despite the fact you don't like or want it:

> - Accept or endure (someone or something unpleasant or disliked) with forbearance:
>
>   - *How was it that she could tolerate such noise?*

- I have to tolerate the use of crutches for another two weeks.